# Can a screen overlay be used to simulate user actions on Android and iPhone?

Tags: android, iphone

Both Android and iPhone:

With a screen overlay, can it be used to activate parts of the screen, thereby simulating user actions, activating the underlying action areas on the screen, i.e. scrolling?

I found this [floating window library](https://github.com/recruit-lifestyle/FloatingView) but that may do the trick on Android, wondering if anyone else has suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

> With a screen overlay, can it be used to activate parts of the screen, thereby simulating user actions, activating the underlying action areas on the screen, i.e. scrolling?

No, on Android. Faking input into other apps has significant security ramifications. On Android, accessibility services have some limited ability to do this sort of thing, which is why Google is starting to restrict their distribution. And, of course, on a rooted device you will have more options.

Comment: I saw a post starting that floating window library could do it.  Are you saying that on a rooted device it will work?

Comment: What about on a desktop application that links to your phone where mouse clicks can do this?

Comment: @ElHaix: "I saw a post starting that floating window library could do it" -- a floating window simply floats. It handles output, not input. "Are you saying that on a rooted device it will work?" -- I am saying that there are techniques involving root that can simulate input. An app with a floating window will not gain that ability simply by running on a rooted device. "What about on a desktop application that links to your phone where mouse clicks can do this?" -- tools like `scrcpy` rely on specific debugging capabilities that are not available to on-device apps.